# LoadingPanel - Waiting for Vector & WFS loading

Tags: vector, openlayers, gis

I have vector layer with WFS protocol. and because I have a huge amount of data, there is a while before features loaded on the map.

So i need to tell user to wait a moment until they load by display a "waiting" animation.

I found this https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/26072/waiting-for-vector-wfs-loading

and tried it with no luck so far.

here is what I did:

- I placed the LoadingPanel.js
- I added this stylesheet:

  ```
  .olControlLoadingPanel {

          background-image:url(loading.gif);

          position: relative;

          width: 195px;

          height: 11px;

          background-position:center;

          background-repeat:no-repeat;

          display: none;

      }

   </style>
  ```
- and finally added the LoadingPanel control :

`map.addControl(new OpenLayers.Control.LoadingPanel());`

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

- Modify your stylesheet

  ```
  .olControlLoadingPanel {
      background-image:url(loading.gif);
      position: relative;
      width: 100%; 
      height: 100%;
      background-position:center;
      background-repeat:no-repeat;
      display: none;
  }
  ```
- Add your the LoadingPanel control to the map, and then make it visible

  ```
  var loadingPanel = new OpenLayers.Control.LoadingPanel();
  this.map.addControl(loadingPanel);
  //set visible the control
  loadingPanel.show();
  ```